# UIBarButtonItem Custom view in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am making a custom bar buttons for uinavigationbar, I am using following code

```
 UIImageView *backImgView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_back.png"]]; [backImgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backImgView];
[backButton setTarget:self];
[backButton setAction:@selector(BackBtn)];
checkIn_NavBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

The problem is it is not calling its action. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can I see on your BackBtn method?

Comment: What is checkIn_NavBar? Do you have a strong reference to it? Why not use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?

Comment: try and use  [checkIn_NavBar setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton]; or self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backButton;

Comment: checkIn_NavBar have a strong reference and BackBtn method is not being called.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**From Apple documentation:** 
Initializes a new item using the specified custom view.

```
- (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView
```

Parameters
customView
A custom view representing the item.
Return Value
Newly initialized item with the specified properties.

Discussion:
**The bar button item created by this method does not call the action method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response.**

Solution: "Create button with your background image (set action to this button) and init bar button with this button". For example:

```
UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,25,25)
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(BackBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Comment: Good answer, but: The docu says: "When creating a custom button—that is a button with the type UIButtonTypeCustom—the frame of the button is set to (0, 0, 0, 0) initially. Before adding the button to your interface, you should update the frame to a more appropriate value." So you should definitively set the frame of the button, else you won't see nothing!b v

Comment: @ReinhardMänner - you saved my lfe, man! Also, thats a terrible default value for a frame...

Comment: @katzenhut - glad that I could help you, and you are completely right about the default value...

Comment: I added the specification of the frame, and made it 75x44 which is similar to the default UIBarButtonItem.  Make ithe image 25x25 viewable area surrounded by transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this using following code:

```
UIButton *nxtBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[nxtBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_next.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nxtBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(NextBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nxtBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 31)];
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:nxtBtn];

checkIn_NavBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem=nextButton;
```

Comment: So your adding a button onto a button. That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: @Popeye `UIBarButtonItem` isn't a button, check out it's inheritance.

Comment: @BryanBryce Bloody hell this is old, I think I was more saying `UIBarButtonItem` was a form of a button in itself not necessarily saying it was inherited from `UIButton` - thank you for testing my memory.#