# Take away part of UIBarButton

Tags: ios, image, uibarbuttonitem

Currently I have a navigation bar with a bar button on it which was created in my storyboard:

[image: Notes]

I would like to take away the white part of the bar button and keep only the image. Is their a way to do that?

When I try this code there is no bar button:

```
UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"19-gear.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: Show your code for creating the bar button item.

Comment: @rmaddy I created it in my Storyboard.

Comment: Is there some way to set the button's style to "plain" instead of "bordered"? That's what would be done in code anyway.

Comment: @rmaddy You can but I am getting a warning saying "Plain is not supported by Navigation Item"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,60,34);
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"19-gear.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

you haven't set the frame of your button that why its not coming on your navigation bar.

Comment: yeah, nice catch on your part... +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a CustomView?

As in [`UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:)

Then you have control over exactly how the button (which you have to supply the graphic for) appears.

[Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057567/uibarbuttonitem-custom-view-in-uinavigationbar) that talks about how to set up a custom view'ed to respond to clicks.

***EDIT:***

Here's a bit of code that's way over the top in terms of error checking, but I'm pretty certain something isn't quite right in your set up.  Using this, we might be able to find out what it is.

```
UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
if(btn)
{
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"19-gear.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
    if(barButton)
    {

        if(self.navigationController)
        {
            if(self.navigationController.navigationBar)
            {
                if(self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem)
                {
                    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
                } else {
                    NSLog( @"why is topItem null?");
                }
            } else {
                NSLog( @"navigationBar appears to be null");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"navigationController is null");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"did not create UIBarButtonItem");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"did not create UIButton");
}
```

Comment: What should I use as the custom view?

Comment: You can actually hand a "`UIButton`" as a custom view.  :-)  Take a look at ghazi_jaffary's answer in the linked question above.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to this this in storyboard?

Comment: not that I know of... to use "`initWithCustomView`", it needs to be done programmatically.

Comment: I suspect one of the items in the big dot reference line (e.g. "`self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem`") is nil.

Comment: So how can I add the bar button to my navigation bar?

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton; is getting called but the view is showing nothing