# Customize navigation bar button in iOS6

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, customization

### Update - One Possible Solution

Based on answer given by Alexander Merchi in this post ([UIBarButtonItem Custom view in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057567/uibarbuttonitem-custom-view-in-uinavigationbar)), a solution is found. But still don't know how to change the position of the image properly.

```
UIButton *btn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28.0f, 28.0f)]; // 28 points is the width or height of the button image
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickMenuButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

[image]

### Original Post

In iOS 6, the goal is like this:

[image]

while current result is like this:

[image]

My code is

```
btnMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]
                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self 
                                          action:@selector(onClickMenuButton)];
```

button.png is this the white circle with white three bars inside and a tranparent background.

Comment: change leftButton.bounds in my answer. It should work to change the position.

Answer (score 8):

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button-normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout-hover"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logOut) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: To @Dinesh, do you know how to change the position of the image? I tried to give some offset like CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30); but the image is not moved.

Comment: Since you are setting a custom button as the bar button i think this will not help you much.. as it will always tries to take the x axis of  bar button itself..

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll try some other ways tomorrow :D

Comment: This makes a white button, how can I make it black?

Answer (score 1):

I am accomplishing it by

```
 UIImageView *uView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back_ontouch_scr11.png"]];
    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    leftButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, uView.frame.size.width, uView.frame.size.height );
    [leftButton setImage:uView.image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back_normal_scr11.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *aButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
    self.scrollView.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aButton;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi @mihirmehta, do you know how to change the position of the image? I tried to give some offset like CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30); but the image is not moved.

Comment: it should move. better ask your designer to change the image in such way that it looks proper with current frame