# Why can I not drag UIBarButtonItem onto navigation bar?

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard, xcode6, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having a little bit of an issue. When I place the `UIBarButtonItem` on the tab bar controller it works perfectly, it displays as it should:
[image: diagram]

However, I can't put a button onto where the black square is. Does anyone know how I could do this non-programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably add a `Navigation Item` by dragging it from the Object Library to the place where you have marked in black and then try adding a Bar Button Item on the right. It should work

Comment: Hey there, thanks very much for getting back to me. If I add it in there it doesn't show in the window where the black square is, it only shows it where the green lines are on that diagram.

Comment: Oh, I didn't quite see the Navigation Controller there. You should drag a `Navigation Item` from the Object Library and put it on the Navigation Bar of the third view controller (the one you have marked in black) and then add a Bar Button Item in that Navigation Bar. It should work Modified my answer :)

Comment: Works!! Thanks very much Anuj!

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBar wants only UIBarButtonItem. You can create one with custom View programmatically. Show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058345/717193