# Assigning custom image to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to assign a custom dynamic image to a navigation item; by doing as follows the image shows but the button does not trigger its action - it does not even register the click, as it were disabled:

```
-(void) updateSanghaButton{
    UIImage* sanghaImage=[[SanghaModelProvider sharedProvider] burnedImageForMeditators];
    UIImageView* sanghaView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:sanghaImage];
    self.sanghaNavigationButton.customView=sanghaView;
    self.sanghaNavigationButton.target=self;
    self.sanghaNavigationButton.action=@selector(showSangha:);
    self.sanghaNavigationButton.enabled=YES;
}
```

Conversely if I use code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *graphButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:   [UIImage imageNamed:@"GraphButton.png"]
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                               target:self
                                                               action:@selector(graphButton)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = graphButton;
```

as at [UIBarButtonItem Custom view in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057567/uibarbuttonitem-custom-view-in-uinavigationbar), the button triggers the action but the image is not shown.

How do I attain both objectives?

Comment: maybe you need to reload your navigation or assign it  again

Comment: As a matter of fact it i easier than I thought: [self.sanghaNavigationButton setImage:sanghaImage]; does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code:

```
[self.sanghaNavigationButton setImage:sanghaImage];
```

just does the job. Assuming of course the button was already on the storyboard and there was an outlet to it, as in my own case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UIButton *btnSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnSetting setBackgroundImage:imgSetting forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnSetting.frame = CGRectMake(0, 7, imgSetting.size.width, imgSetting.size.height);
        [btnSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(showSangha:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *rightbaritem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnSetting];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=@[rightbaritem];
```

Answer (score 0):

first sure

about your **UIImage isn't nil** .
after that you can set the navigation bar with custom image by this way :

```
 self.sanghaNavigationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButtonImage"] style:(UIBarButtonItemStylePlain) target:self action:@selector(myAction)];   
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.sanghaNavigationButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage* imagebackbutton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splace_logo"];
    UIButton *btnback = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [btnback setBackgroundImage:imagebackbutton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnback addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnback];
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=mailbutton;