# How squeeze more icons into a Navigation Bar or Toolbar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to get just one more icon into my Navigation Bar, but can't figure out how to adjust the width to get more room.

Using standard BarButtonItems and using the storyboard to build, there seems to be a limit of 14 icons in portrait mode on iPad. This is an iPad only app.

Here is what I get when I add a 15th icon:

[image]

You can see the "page" icon is on top of a "+" icon.

There is no setting that I can find in the interface builder that allows for adjusting the BarButton sizes. I can't seem to find a programmatic solution either. However, I can find numerous examples of apps with 16 or more icons.

I haven't tried (yet) to change the Navigation Bar to a Toolbar (and don't really see an obvious solution there anyway).

Anyone have an idea how to squeeze just a little more space so I can fit in one more icon?

Comment: you can build custom nav bar with scrollable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `UIBarButtonItems` using `initWithCustomView:`. This way you have full control over items frame and you can make it smaller.

#### Example

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-image.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 43, 30);

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight problem with bear with me's implementation. The event has to be handled by the UIImageView used to create the custom view. I found an easier implementation in another question to stackoverflow. It involves making the customView a custom UIButton. See: [UIBarButtonItem Custom view in UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057567/uibarbuttonitem-custom-view-in-uinavigationbar)

Results:

[image]

Here is my nearly complete (but not optimized) implementation in Swift.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account

    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

   //create a blank image for padding
    var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)  
    var size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)            
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let notButtonBig = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIImageView(image: image))

    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 4, 30)
    size = CGSizeMake(4, 30)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let notButtonSmall = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIImageView(image: image))



//clear - a regular old BarButton

    let clearButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "btn_clicked:")



//undo - customView BarButton

    var undoBt: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    undoBt.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    undoBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "Undo"), forState: .Normal)
    undoBt.addTarget(self, action: "undoBtn:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    var undoButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: undoBt)

/*
a lot more buttons here - deleted for readability
*/

//add buttons to navBar with notButtonSmall for padding

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [ clearButton, notButtonSmall, undoButton, notButtonSmall,pencilButton, notButtonSmall, penButton, notButtonSmall,eraserButton, notButtonSmall,selectButton, notButtonSmall,pasteButton, notButtonSmall,insertButton]
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [ nextButton, notButtonSmall,previousButton, notButtonSmall, palmGuardButton, notButtonSmall, settingsButton, notButtonSmall, filesButton, notButtonSmall, sendButton, notButtonSmall, pagesButton]

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)


    func btn_clicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Do something
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func undoBtn(sender: AnyObject!) {
    print("undo")
}

func btn_clicked(sender: AnyObject!) {
    print("clear")
}
```

}